# In HTML, how can I have a border and fill the container?

Tags: html, css

The following code snippet shows a div in a body. Both have height and width at 100%. The div has a border. The problem is that the browsers make the content box of the div the same size as the body, sending the bottom and right borders out of view. I'm obliged to keep the 100% rules, the whole layout depends on them. How can I make my borders appear? What am I doing wrong?

Simon

```
<html>
    <body style="width:100%;height:100%;">
        <div id="bdiv" style="height:100%;width:100%;border:2px solid green;">Difficult to remain positive in such conditions</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Remove default margin of body

2) Set `box-sizing: border-box;` the div so that the border is rendered within the div

```
body
{
    margin:0;
}
div
{
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/buRZQ/1/)**

Comment: Note that Firefox *still* does not support this, and you must use `-moz-box-sizing: border-box` there.

Comment: Also `<html>` element needs to have `height:100%` or an explicit height as a percentage value of `height` property is relative to the height of box's containing block.

Comment: Works like a charm. Very impressive.